# Is there a shortcut for %in%?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have searched unsuccessfully for a keyboard shortcut for `%in%` in R using RStudio. Wondering if anyone here has figured this out? I have tried all the combinations I could think of.

Comment: Is %in% not the shortcut?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In RStudio I usually use the shortcut for pipe operator Ctrl+Shift+M and just replace the '>' symbol for 'in'.

Comment: See: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-promise-pipe/9795/4?u=jasonaizkalns for details on leveraging either code snippets and/or add-ins within RStudio.

Comment: Try customizing one(if it doesn't exist already): [Custom bindings](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts).

Comment: ```snippet in
 %in%``` and then when you can type `in` and then hit *Shift + Tab* and it inserts ```%in%```.

Comment: Shift + 5, i, n, Shift + 5

Answer (score 8):

An answer years later, in case this is still of interest.

You can get this shortcut by using the [addinexamples](https://github.com/rstudio/addinexamples) package.

1. Install the package:

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/addinexamples", type = "source")`

2. Restart R
3. Go to *Tools* -> *Addins* -> *Browse Addins*
4. Click on *Keyboard Shortcuts...*. You will see the shortcut for `%in%`is now `Ctrl + Shift + I`. You can change the shortcut by clicking on it and running the shortcut you wish.

[image]